# Is there a way to continuously change a certain value without stopping the main loop?

Tags: python, rest, mqtt

I want to program that changes a rooms lights. The system runs on a controller that I can access via MQTT and REST. I have a way to change the intensity but it is very abrupt. Because I want the rest of the system to continue running while the change is happening (because I have Sensors running the rest of the lighting) I can't just use a loop to steadily increase the intensity. I looked into Timers but I can't get them to work properly for what I need. Is there a way to do that?

Here is my Problem with the loop:

```
client.message_callback_add(path("zones",Office,"devices",Sensor1_Presence,"data","presence"), on_message_Presence_callback)
client.message_callback_add(path("zones",Office,"devices",Sensor2_Presence,"data","presence"), on_message_colorchange_callback)

#client.message_callback_add(path("zones","#"), on_message_callback)

startTimer()
WeatherTimer()

client.connect(MQTT_HOST, port=MQTT_PORT)
client.loop_forever()
```

I want to be able to start and stop the function (preferably with a bool)

I have a change function that changes the specific parameters already:

```
def change_parameter(URL, parameter_name ,parameter_value):

r = requests.put(
    f"https://{MQTT_HOST}/rest/v1/{URL}",
    headers=litecom_headers(),
    verify=False,
    json={f"{parameter_name}": parameter_value}
)
return r.status_code
```

Is there a way to do what I want to do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the python script controlling your lights running on your desktop pc?

If so, you most certainly have at least 2 cpu cores at your disposal and can make use of python's [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to run your parameter changing function in parallel. Then you can just gradually change your parameter in small steps until you reach the desired value.
To get a smooth effect you then just have to experiment with the step-size and the sleep value between the steps until you are satisfied with the results.

Pseudo-ish implementation:

```py
def change_param_smooth(URL, parameter_name, target_value, stepsize, duration):
    current_value = 0 // get the current value from your device
    while current_value < target_value:
        current_value += step_size
        # avoid overshooting
        if current_value > target_value:
            current_value = target_value
        change_parameter(URL, parameter_name, current_value)
        time.sleep(duration)
```